# How to use generators with kedro?

Tags: python-3.x, pipeline, kedro, generator-expression

Thanks to [David Beazley's slides on Generators](https://www.dabeaz.com/generators/) I'm quite taken with using generators for data processing in order to keep memory consumption minimal. Now I'm working on my first kedro project, and my question is how I can use generators in kedro. When I have a node that yields a generator, and then run it with `kedro run --node=example_node`, I get the following error:

```
DataSetError: Failed while saving data to data set MemoryDataSet().
can't pickle generator objects
```

Am I supposed to always load all my data into memory when working with kedro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi @ilja to do this you may need to change the type of `assignment` operation that `MemoryDataSet` applies.

In your catalog, declare your datasets explicitly, change the `copy_mode` to one of `copy` or `assign`. I think `assign` may be your best bet here...

https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/kedro.io.MemoryDataSet.html

I hope this works, but am not 100% sure.

Comment: Thanks @datajoely! For those like me who need to process this answer a bit: In the `catalog.yml` declare the `type` of the MemoryDataSet as `kedro.io.MemoryDataSet` and the `copy_mode` as `assign`. The `filepath` can be omitted.